People picked off one at a time in an apartment building
This was a movie (80's or 90's?) where a bunch of people were (held up?) in an apartment building. There were people outside that would just stand there looking at the people in the building.
I think something happened and one-by-one, the people inside were being picked off by something.
I only really remember the part where two people were looking down onto the open parking lot at a bunch of other people just standing there in the dark (only a parking lot light was lit).

Please elaborate. I may have a couple of wild guesses, but that's all they'll be without more details. Also, please explain what you mean by 'a bunch of people were we help up in an apartment building'. That doesn't make much sense.

@Walt ... I would bet English is not Richard's first language or he's a very poor proof reader. I think it is supposed to be held up, but I'm with you, this needs more info.

That was my guess too, but it seemed too far off... Now edited.

Based on "people outside that would just stand there looking at the people in the building", I'm going to say it's John Carpenter's Prince of Darkness, (1987).  

A priest (Donald Pleasence) invites Professor Howard Birack (Victor
  Wong) and a group of academics and students to join him in the
  basement of an abandoned 1950s church called Saint Goddard's Church in
  Los Angeles, where he requests their assistance in investigating a
  mysterious cylinder containing a constantly swirling, green liquid.

Turns out it's the Anti-Christ.  Things start going bad when

small jets of liquid escape the cylinder and possess the group one by
  one to use them against the remaining survivors.
...
Attempts to escape the building are thwarted by a mass of possessed
  street people who surround the building, barricade the doors from the
  outside, and kill two of the group.

The possessed street people outside spend much of the movie just standing there looking up at the building.
